# 'has induced in' - Why 'in'?

Tags: difference, prepositions, legalese

Source: p 90, *The Law of Contract*, 5 ed (2012), by O’Sullivan and Hilliard

> Spence (1999) has suggested that estoppel might solve many of the problems dealt with
>   in this chapter. His approach asks what assumptions the recipient of the services has
>   [induced](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/induce?q=induced#induce__13) **in** the other party, whether the other party has relied on these assumptions to
>   his detriment, and if so, whether it would be ‘unconscionable’ for the recipient not to
>   remedy this detriment.

Please explain why the preposition must be **in**? I guess that the meaning is: His approach asks what assumptions the recipient of the services has **caused** the other party  **to adopt**, ... But I would've written induced FOR or TO or TOWARDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> His approach asks what assumptions the recipient of the services has induced in the other party

A Google search gives the following definitions for *induce*:

> 1. succeed in persuading or influencing (someone) to do something.
> 2. bring about or give rise to.

When you say *induce*, you are trying to manipulate someone's internal state or thinking so they choose to do something.  (You aren't trying to change external circumstances to make them do something - that would be to *compel*, and you aren't directly trying to make them do something - that would be to *coerce*.)

So, think about it: where is the "thing" that you are inducing?  It starts *in* the person you are trying to induce to do X.

Comment: You thought through your answer well. To manipulate someone's internal state or thinking would require the preposition, in. Great clarity!

Comment: @Jim +1 I agree; it's a supernal answer! To ultrasawblade: +1. Thank you effusively for your detail.